# Touch, Framework 4.7, multiple windows & Windows Creator Update

Tags: wpf, touch, windows-10

Since **Windows 10 creator update**, we have a touch compliant WPF App that crashes:
Crash occurs when we are moving from one window to another on a **touch action**.

Here is the revelant part of the stack :

```
Source : PresentationCore
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispStylusDevice.get_TabletDevice()
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusTouchDeviceBase..ctor(StylusDeviceBase stylusDevice)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.PromoteMainToMouse(StagingAreaInputItem stagingItem)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.PromoteStoredItemsToMouse(WispStylusTouchDevice touchDevice)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispStylusTouchDevice.OnManipulationEnded(Boolean cancel)
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.OnManipulationCancel()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationLogic.ReportFrame(ICollection`1 manipulators)
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.ReportFrame()
   at System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDevice.RemoveManipulator(IManipulator manipulator)
   at System.Windows.Input.Manipulation.TryRemoveManipulator(UIElement element, IManipulator manipulator)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PromoteMainToManipulation(UIElement manipulatableElement, TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.Capture(IInputElement element, CaptureMode captureMode)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PromoteMainToManipulation(UIElement manipulatableElement, TouchEventArgs touchEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.RaiseTouchUp()
   at System.Windows.Input.TouchDevice.ReportUp()
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.PromoteMainUpToTouch(WispStylusDevice stylusDevice, StagingAreaInputItem stagingItem)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.PromoteMainToTouch(ProcessInputEventArgs e, StylusEventArgs stylusEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.InputManagerProcessInput(Object oInput)
   at System.Windows.Input.StylusWisp.WispLogic.PreProcessInput(Object sender, PreProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   ...
```

Let me be precise, the product is p**erfectly working on windows 7/8/8.1/10(non creator)** and we do not use any Wacom or stylus device except our finger :)

If you have any idea, let me know and i will test it.